# Change Content if menu item change Ant.design and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I create a layout for my app using ant.design layout, now i want change content depand which menu item user are clicked

I use also React-router, and if i chose for exemple home content add in bottom of page

This is my menu

```
 <Menu  mode="inline">
   <Menu.Item key="1">
      <span>Home</span>
          <Link to='/'></Link>
  </Menu.Item>
 </Menu>
```

i have also in index component

```
<Content style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}>

 </Content>
```

In my home component i have like this  <

```
Content style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}>
                <p>Welcome</p>
              </Content>
```

So how to add home in correct layout not in buttom and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your layout, you should be following this structure in your main component,

```
<Layout>
      <Sider>Sider</Sider>
      <Layout>
        <Header>Header</Header>
         <Content>
           <p>Welcome</p>
         </Content>
        <Footer>Footer</Footer>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
```

Comment: Hi @Rohith Murali, thanks to response, but i do like this in my main component

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this scenario, coz there is very little code that can be debugged

Comment: yes of course @Rohith Murali, if a added this to my welcome component other layout created, so i want change juste content

Comment: Please create a codesandbox, i will help you to sort this out.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/7z0n81m5v0 I have added router and corrected the structure...Check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173955/discussion-between-rohith-murali-and-akram).

Comment: Did you check the new sandbox page??

Comment: @yes, thank you so much, i will accept your answer, i stay one thing how to add link to menu item